# Portuguese keyboard not writing special characters on Ubuntu Studio with any desktop app

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

This seems like a bug.

Portuguese keyboard is not writing this characters " **á ã â** "
on Ubuntu Studio with any desktop app. Text editors including.
It works on browsers. Including in this StackExchange text input window.

On my US keyboard with Portuguese layout if i type " **] \ |** " i get " **á ã â** ".

All works well with Kubuntu.
What setting/config file do i compare with Kubuntu so i can apply it in ubuntu studio?

I posted this issue on ubuntu forum, specifically under ubuntu studio flavor, but did not get a reply.

Any of you using Ubuntu Studio, having this issue (with portuguese or other foreign language) other than US?
Any solution?

There is nothing about this issue on google.

Comment: Is there a specific application that you're trying to work with? For instance, Studio Controls isn't localized, and there's a ton of audio applications that also aren't locallized.

Comment: @ErichEickmeyer: I suppose you mean localized in the sense that menus and messages are or can be translated. But that should not be related to the described problem, which is about typing.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and explain *how* exactly you try to type special characters.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson

I edited. Is it more clear now?

Comment: @7q5s: Not good enough. ;-) Can you please tell us which keys you use when trying to type those characters.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson

Done :)

Comment: @7q5s: It's still not expressed clearly. While it's correct that **ç** can be typed by pressing the **;** key on a US keyboard, the **áãâ** characters are created by pressing some dead key followed by pressing **A**. So possibly your problem is that dead keys are not working on the Ubuntu Studio desktop applications. But in that case typing **ç** should work. Are you sure it does not?

Comment: You are right. **ç** works.

What setting/config file do i compare with Kubuntu so i can apply it in ubuntu studio?

Comment: Not sure about a specific setting, it may be a bug. My suggestion is that you create another user for test purposes on your Ubuntu Studio install, log in as that user, and see if the issue is present for that user as well.

Answer (score 0):

What solved a similar problem for me in Ubuntu (not Studio) 23.04:

- installing both the Portuguese (Portugal) keyboard and the Portuguese System Language
- Setting the system language for Portuguese and the keyboard input method system for IBus
- Logging out and in

After this, special accented characters worked as intended, I just reverted the system language to English because due to personal preferences and it kept working.